# If it isn't [someone's name]!

Tags: omissibility

"If it isn't [a name]!" can be used to show surprise when you bump into someone, but it is not a complete sentence. What is omitted (and understood) here?

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What has disappeared from *if it isn’t [name]!* is an oath, euphemistically expressed or not, along a familiar pattern:

> …may thunder strike me dead if e're i lov'd before i saw your all commanding beauty … Lewis Maidwell, *The Loving Enemies* (comedy), 1680. EEBO

Restore the oath and you get a complete sentence. A few examples:

> “Lord save us!” said Matty, “if it isn’t his honour. You are ten thousand times welcome …” — Anne Newport Royall, *The Tennessean* (novel), 1827. COHA
>
> “Why, it a'n't! Yes, I'll be switched if it isn't Harry Beckworth rose from the dead!” — Caroline M. Kirkland,  *A New Home — Who'll Follow?*, 1839. COHA
>
> “Lord bless me if it isn't young marster's sister.” — Mary Jane Holmes, *Tempest and Sunshine*, 1854. COHA
>
> "Eh? Why, [*hang me, if it isn't Old King Brady*](https://books.google.de/books?id=mfBLxAeDqTYC&pg=PA23&dq=%22hang+me+if%22+%22King+Brady%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY6d2O3YnkAhUBC-wKHWbwCyUQ6AEIJzAA). What are you doing here, you old fox ?" — “The Bradys and ‘Black Jack,’” *Secret Service* (detective magazine), 26 Feb. 1904, 23.

As @FumbleFingers has commented that the British minced oath of *blow me down* is commonly completed with an *if* clause, there is a gem I  couldn’t resist:

> Why [*blow me down if it isn't*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.225423/page/n17) the local glamour girl — come to Daddy, Thelma! — R.F. Delderfield, *Worm’s Eye View: A Comedy*, *Embassy Successes*, v. I & II (1945–46), 11.

The complete form has certainly not died out, though perhaps living on with more contemporary swearing:

> 'F*** me [*if it ain't Burkett 359*](https://books.google.de/books?id=gsk6CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT39&lpg=PT39&dq=%22fuck%20me%20if%20it%22&source=bl&ots=0y_s_ZgYTW&sig=ACfU3U1BEtE9EHN19xcKMLQ3Giu-TQIMlg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj7fOf4InkAhVI2KQKHYxyDTwQ6AEwDHoECAkQAQ),' — Jeremy Cameron, *It was an Accident*, 2015.

Comment: I'd never have thought of this for myself, but as soon as I see it, I'm convinced you're quite right. By way of supporting evidence, I asked Google NGrams what would be [the most likely word to follow the "minced oath" ***blow me down.***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blow+me+down+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cblow%20me%20down%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bblow%20me%20down%20if%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bblow%20me%20down%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bblow%20me%20down%20for%3B%2Cc0) As you can probably guess, it's ***if***, by some margin.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks! I had to add a particularly delicious example from your search, but got the full bibliographic from archive.org. This is from one of the first plays to grace the London stage after the war.

Comment: _I'll be switched_ means I'll be beaten with a thin stick.

Comment: Excellent research (I'm trying to work out how you went about it. Can you search for ", if it isn't?"?)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Google and the BYU corpora can search for “if it is n’t.” A few I got with “me if it.”

Answer (score 4):

The expression could possibly be considered a *protasis* (dependent clause) which is missing its *apodosis* (independent clause):

- If it isn't Jack Smith, I will be surprised.

But a better explanation is that the omission consists of what the *Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (p444) calls an *initiator*, i.e. a word to preface a statement. In this case this speaker would probably not have said simply:

- If it isn't Jack Smith!

but

- Well, if it isn't Jack Smith!

or

- Why, if it isn't Jack Smith.

As the CGEL states in the section *sentence types and discourse functions* (p842):

> Negative *if-clauses*, usually preceded by *well* or *why*, are used to express surprise:
>
> - Well, if it isn't the manager himself! ['It is  indeed the manager himself!']
> - Why, if it isn't Susan! ['It is indeed Susan']

So, the expression can stand by itself as what has elsewhere been called  an [emotive interjection](https://books.google.de/books/about/Emotive_Interjections_in_British_English.html?id=7ar3jgEACAAJ&redir_esc=y), in this case to express surprise and perhaps pleasure.

Comment: I'll be a monkey's uncle if someone can tell me what to do with Karl's answer. +1. What's missing is what you'll do *if it isn't*. Commonly used is a phrase, with a four letter *s* word, about soiling yourself.